# JSON - how to highlight duplicated items in a specific column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting

I have a microsoft lists where the ID for each episode is a number. I want to format th ID Column so that each time a new item is added, if the ID column is duplicated from an existing ID it appears red.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Is this SharePoint out of the box `ID`? If yes, it should always be unique.

Answer (score 0):

ID column should always be updated by code or it should be autgenerated to reduce the duplication.

Currently JSON Formatter only work with formation and changing the layout of data.

But Still if you want check the dublicate value and highlight it. Customization is required.

In order to fullfill this requirment you have to use SharePoint Extension - Field Customizer  and in item level you can build your logic.

Answer (score 0):

List Formatting can only look at one row at a time. Unfortunately, this means you can't compare values against other values in the list using formatting.

If the goal is to prevent duplicate IDs (not list ids), you could enable "Enforce Unique Values" option for the field. You will be prompted to create an index, but this will prevent users from adding list items where the value for the field has already been used in another list item in that same list.

Expand **More options** to find this option.

[image]

If you are wanting to allow duplicate values, but flag them visually then you'll have to use custom code such as a Field Customizer (SPFx).

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, the ootb SP ID is unique and we cannot change the background color in this column.

If you want to use the background color in columns, you could create a new column, and try to use conditional formatting.

For example:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this does not work since ID is numeric variable... And that is my problem